# Matching Records In Real Time

Tags: java, hashmap

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I'm sending some packets over the cellular networks. I'm also sniffing the traffic to check a response to these packets. The response may come anywhere within the 10 hour window.

the packets that I send are all unique (to and from) and I would like to know the best way to match the packets and responses.

I can create a hashmap and put every packet sent in it real time and match it with the response when it comes back. At which point, the has map entry either stays in the hashmap or gets deleted (after being responded to).

So, now the question: What will be the best way to achieve this considering we have 2000 packets sent every minute? Will hashmap be robust enough? What about search times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think HashMap alone will be robust enough as it is not thread-safe. I would give a try to **ConcurrentHashMap**.

As for larger amount of data look for some **cache** implementation - these usually have the ability to overflow to disk and have time expiration  so you get the clean-ups for free.

Comment: Thank you for detecting this. I'm using Concurrent HashMap. Speaking of cache, I did some research and think that an alternative could be MongoDB. Ofcourse, we will have to consider its performance compared to Hashmaps when the number of entries in the map could potentially exceed 10 million (e.g. 100 bytes each)

Answer (score 0):

A hashmap will certainly be "robust" enough.  At 2000 packets sent per minute and assuming an average response time of 5 hours, you could have 600,000 packets outstanding.  Assuming your device has sufficient memory to hold the packets, and you allocate a large enough hashtable (say 600,000 with a load factor of .75), then lookups will be very fast.

Look at the javadoc for [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, you shouldn't have problems, provided that the `hashCode` method of the keys of the map is properly written and allows distributing the potential 1,200,000 keys with as few collisions as possible. `HashMap` is O(1).

But memory might be a problem. In the worst case, you'll have 1,200,000 entries in your map. If each of them takes 400 bytes (which is not much, but I don't know what your packets contain), you already need 460 MBs.

Comment: The server is a HP blade running on CentOS with 32 GB of RAM so I don't think memory will be a problem. I was more concerned about HashMap lookup taking too long but thanks for brining up the O(1) point.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is "robust" (in the sense that it works). Another consideration is device memory.

Let's see: 10 hours * 60 minuts/hour * 2000 packets/minute = 1.200.000. For a HashMap, this means at least 2.400.00 pointers, in 32 bit architecture 9.600.000 Bytes. Just for the structure of the HashMap, assuming no colisions (extra 4 bytes per collisions) and excluding the size of the data itself (keys and values). Memory will be an issue.

In relation to time, it depends of how much the equals() and hashCode() functions take, and also in the number of collisions in the HashMap (number of collisions == numer of execution of equals, more or less). Without that data it cannot be calculated.